# java.sql.Timestamp value; nested exception is java.sql.SQLDataException in Spring-boot project

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, spring-boot, spring-mvc

I'm building a project with spring boots, checking the status of the Internet through control, and I'm in the process of a DB connection.

I'm trying to do '**MyBatis**', but there's an error.

This is a list of my directories:
[image: directories]

**MinitoringdataApplication.java**

```java
package com.smartcore.mn.springboot;

import org.mybatis.spring.annotation.MapperScan;
import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;

@SpringBootApplication
@MapperScan(basePackages = "com.smartcore.mn.springboot")
public class MinitoringdataApplication {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(MinitoringdataApplication.class, args);
    }

}
```

**ServletInitializer.java**

```java
package com.smartcore.mn.springboot;

import org.springframework.boot.builder.SpringApplicationBuilder;
import org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.support.SpringBootServletInitializer;

public class ServletInitializer extends SpringBootServletInitializer {

    @Override
    protected SpringApplicationBuilder configure(SpringApplicationBuilder application) {
        return application.sources(MinitoringdataApplication.class);
    }

}
```

**ApiController.java**

```java
package com.smartcore.mn.springboot.controller;

import java.time.LocalDateTime;
import java.time.format.DateTimeFormatter;
import java.util.List;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.GetMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RestController;

import com.smartcore.mn.springboot.model.Member;
import com.smartcore.mn.springboot.service.MemberService;

@RestController
public class ApiController {

    @Autowired
    MemberService memberService;


    @GetMapping(path = "/helloWorld")
    public String helloWorld() {
        return LocalDateTime.now().format(DateTimeFormatter.ISO_LOCAL_DATE_TIME);
    }

    @GetMapping(path = "/db")
    public List<Member> selectAllMember() {
         List<Member> members = memberService.getAllMember();
         return members;
    }

}
```

**MemberMapper.interface**

```java
package com.smartcore.mn.springboot.mapper;

import java.util.List;

import org.apache.ibatis.annotations.Mapper;

import com.smartcore.mn.springboot.model.Member;

@Mapper
public interface MemberMapper {
    Member selectMemberById(Long id);
    List<Member> selectAllMember();
    void insertMember(Member member);

}
```

**Member.java**

```java
package com.smartcore.mn.springboot.model;

import java.util.Date;

import org.apache.ibatis.type.Alias;

import com.smartcore.mn.springboot.Exception.IdPasswordNotMatchingException;

import lombok.Data;


@Data
@Alias("member")
public class Member {

    private Long id;
    private String email;
    private String password;
    private String name;
    private Date registerDate;

    public Member(String email, String password, String name, Date registerDate) {
        this.email = email;
        this.password = password;
        this.name = name;
        this.registerDate = registerDate;
    }

    public void setId(Long id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public Long getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public String getEmail() {
        return email;
    }

    public String getPassword() {
        return password;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public Date getRegisterDate() {
        return registerDate;
    }

    public void changePassword(String oldPassword, String newPassword) {
        if (!password.equals(oldPassword))
            throw new IdPasswordNotMatchingException();
        this.password = newPassword;
    }

}
```

**MemberService.java**

```java
package com.smartcore.mn.springboot.service;

import java.util.List;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Service;
import org.springframework.transaction.annotation.Transactional;

import com.smartcore.mn.springboot.mapper.MemberMapper;
import com.smartcore.mn.springboot.model.Member;

@Service
@Transactional
public class MemberService {

    @Autowired
    MemberMapper memberMapper;

    public Member getMemberById(Long id) {
        return memberMapper.selectMemberById(id);
    }

    public List<Member> getAllMember() {
        return memberMapper.selectAllMember();
    }

    public void addMember(Member member) {
        memberMapper.insertMember(member);
    }

}
```

**application.properties**

```
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:mysql://localhost/mydb?serverTimezone=UTC&autoReconnection=true
spring.datasource.username=mydb
spring.datasource.password=mydb
spring.datasource.driver-class-name=com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver
mybatis.type-aliases-package=com.smartcore.mn.springboot.model
logging.level.com.smartcore.mn.springboot.mapper=TRACE
```

[image: xmlfile]

MemberMapper.xml

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<!DOCTYPE mapper PUBLIC "-//mybatis.org//DTD Mapper 3.0//EN"
        "http://mybatis.org/dtd/mybatis-3-mapper.dtd">

<mapper namespace="com.smartcore.mn.springboot.mapper.MemberMapper">

    <select id="selectMemberById" resultType="member">
         SELECT * 
         FROM MEMBER 
         WHERE ID = #{id}
    </select>

    <select id="selectAllMember" resultType="member">
          SELECT * 
          FROM MEMBER
    </select>

    <insert id="insertMember">
      INSERT INTO MEMBER (EMAIL, PASSWORD, NAME, REGDATE)
      VALUES (#{email}, #{password}, #{name}, #{registerDate})
    </insert>

</mapper>
```

**http://localhost:8080/helloworld** is works normally.

But  **http://localhost:8080/db** have see Error

[image: db connect]

I need your solution. Thank you in advance.

**my TABLE**

[image]

Comment: Mapping between the entity and data table is not correct.

Comment: What's wrong problem?

Comment: Show your `Member` table. There are some unexpected columns in your result, I guess, since you are selecting all the column (`SELECT *`). It's a good practice when you clarify the columns you want instead of all.

Comment: @Càphêđen I updated My question;

Comment: Are you sure you are connecting to the correct database? As I see, the database in the connection string is different from your commandline.

Comment: Is `mydb` your database or `spring4fs`?

Comment: @Càphêđen Oh, this is a question, so I changed database name. The database has the same name.

Comment: Try `SELECT EMAIL, PASSWORD, NAME, REGDATE` only or add `id` field to your constructor. Mybatis is trying mapping your `NAME` column to the `regDate` field.

Comment: @Càphêđen I changed `SELECT ID , EMAIL , PASSWORD, NAME FROM MEMBER` but same Error

Comment: No. I mean the columns in result-set should match with the constructor args order.
`SELECT EMAIL, PASSWORD, NAME, REGDATE` should match `Member(String email, String password, String name, Date registerDate)`

Comment: @Càphêđen Oh, thank you. But The ID value is null. How can I guess this one?

Comment: What do you mean *guessing the ID*?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As mentioned in our discussion in comments, MyBatis is trying to map your `NAME` column in result-set to the `registerDate` argument in the `Member` constructor.

Since you did not specify `paramName` for each fields, the order of arg elements in the constructor is error-prone.

Try mapping your result-set to your constructor with correct ordered args:

`Member(String email, String password, String name, Date registerDate)` should match `SELECT EMAIL, PASSWORD, NAME, REGDATE FROM MEMBER`

or

`Member(Long id, String email, String password, String name, Date registerDate)` should match `SELECT * FROM MEMBER`